# How do you use OVER(ORDER BY()) on a table with an existing order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, window-functions

I'd like to achieve the following:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    id AS Col0,
    'constant' AS Col1
    IIF(z < 0, x, 0) AS Col2,
    IIF(z > 0, x, 0) AS Col3,
    SUM(x) OVER(ORDER BY Col2 DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Col4]
FROM y
ORDER BY Col2 DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
```

I am trying to make a cumulative column. The problem is that I'd like to use the tables'  `ORDERBY()` on the `OVER()` dynamically but `OVER(ORDERBY())` does not support index based nor will it accept `Col1` as a column.

How would I go about doing it? I could just as easily do something afterwards in the code but I'd prefer to learn how to do this in pure SQL.

Comment: Can you show sample input and the output you want?  Note the the `ORDER BY` appearing in the `OVER` clause has to do with the window function `SUM()` and _not_ the order of the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `Order By Col2` with the expression used to create Col2

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id AS Col0,
    'constant' AS Col1
    IIF(z < 0, x, 0) AS Col2,
    IIF(z > 0, x, 0) AS Col3,
    SUM(x) OVER(ORDER BY IIF(z > 0, x, 0) DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Col4]
FROM y
ORDER BY Col2 DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. But if I have to order over the constant value it would not accept it though. But I'll probably have to find a way around that regardless.